# Minimum distance from point to surface

Tags: constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, geometry

I’m looking for code that is well-suited to solving a fairly simple minimization problem:

I have a reference point $\mathbf p$ in 3D space, and I want to minimize $\|\mathbf x - \mathbf p\|^2$ subject to a constraint $F(\mathbf x)=0$.

The functions $F$ are very smooth, but typically have no useful convexity properties, and in some cases (not shown below) they might also be very complex and expensive to evaluate. The simple aspects (I think) are that there are only three independent variables, and the objective function is just a quadratic form. The problem comes from engineering geometry or CAD — I’m trying to find the minimum distance from the point $\mathbf p$ to the surface $\{\mathbf x : F(\mathbf x) = 0\}$.

Some examples of typical surfaces are:
Ellipsoid: $F(x,y,z) = 4x^2 + 9y^2 + z^2 - 1$.
Clebsch: $F(x,y,z) =64x^3 + 48x^2z - 192y^2x + 48y^2z - 31z^3 - 54z^2 - 24z$
ThreeHoles: $F(x,y,z) = x(x^2 - 3y^2) -  z(z^2 - 1)$
SchwartzP: $F(x,y,z) = \cos(x) + \cos(y) + \cos(z)$
Scherk: $F(x,y,z) = \sin(z) - \tfrac12 \sinh(x) \sinh(y)$
Costa: $F(x,y,z) = (x^2 + y^2 - 1)z - (x^2 - y^2)$

And here are a few pictures:
[image]

I know that I can attack this problem by solving the equation $(\mathbf x - \mathbf p) \times \nabla F(\mathbf x) = 0$, but I thought using a minimization algorithm might work better.

**My question**: There are dozens of optimization algorithms, and I’m hoping that someone can recommend one (or more) that is well-suited to my problem, perhaps by taking advantage of its simplicity.

Ideally, I’d like to get working code, as opposed to just a mathematical description. I don’t really care what programming language is used. I don’t need great accuracy (5 or 6 good digits would be OK), but speed and reliability are important.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that $\{x:F(x)=0\}$ is a surface, that it has co-dimension $1$? Otherwise one can encode any system $\phi_(x)=0$ via sum-of-squares $F(x)=\sum\phi_i(x)^2$. If it is a surface, then at the optimum point the line to $r$ is orthogonal to the tangent plane, $F'(x)=\lambda (x-r)$, giving generically a full system, but will all critical points of the distance function as solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Yes, we can assume we have a surface. I have considered the equation-solving approach you suggested, but I’m wondering if a minimization approach might work better.

Comment: I realize that the community bot isn’t going to tell me, but I really can’t imagine what’s unclear about my question. Happy to add more info if anyone can tell me what’s missing.

Comment: The approach with Grad(F) in general would have multiple solutions, so to find a true distance to the surface one would need to find all those solutions and compare them.  But geometrically solving a problem like this would be convenient putting  a sphere centered at the test point, and increasing the radius of the sphere gradually until it touches the surface.  This approach can be probably used as the basis of an iterative solution algorithm here.

Comment: The definition of $F(x)$ is missing.  A typical difficulty, even for a smooth function, is distinguishing local minima from a global minimum.  They would share a perpendicularity condition.

Comment: @hardmath. I added some example surface equations.

Comment: Is the function F(x) given with an analytical expression? Do you want to solve many points for one surface?

Comment: Mathematical approaches to such problems have been kicked around at Math.SE, e.g. [Minimum distance between a surface and a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563960/minimum-distance-between-a-surface-and-a-point).

Comment: @AmitHochman. Not necessarily. But we can assume that we have a software function that returns $F(x,y,z)$ at any input point $(x,y,z)$. And yes, I typically do want to calculate the distance from many points.

Comment: @hardmath. Thanks. But the problem you mentioned is much simpler than mine, and can be solved algebraically. I’m interested in numerical methods that will work on a broader range of problems.

Comment: If you want to find the distance from one surface to many points, you could approximate the surface with a 3D mesh, perhaps quite a coarse one and a finer one, and compute the nearest neighbors among the vertices. There are methods for doing this efficiently. The results could be refined in various ways, starting by finding the distance to the nearest polygon.

Comment: If you discretize your domain and compute the distance transform then you can start a walk from $p$ along the negative gradient of the distance field. In the worst case scenario you will end up choosing one of many possible equivalent minima on the discrete grid. The only error that you will have there would come from the discretisation of the domain. To speed this up you could have some adaptive structure on top in order to reduce the required resolution. Another option would be to shoot rays from $p$ in several directions and pick the intersection that is closest.

Comment: If you have a bound around the object (e.g. axis-aligned bounding box) then you can have the rays be shot in the direction of the box only. I suggest using a low-discrepnacy sequence for distributing the rays. Also you should distribute those uniformly over the solid angle subtended by the bounding box of your surface.

Comment: @AmitHochman. Thanks. Meshing is a pretty good way to find approximate solutions. And then those solutions can be polished. But there are lots of details to worry about. For example, how good do the approximate solutions need to be to ensure that the polishing succeeds. And what’s the best way to do the polishing (which is really the crux of my question).

Comment: You could mesh the volume, solve the eikonal equation or a p-poisson equation for the distance function, find the point with the smallest distance and then refine the mesh there and repeat. That would give you a method with provable error convergence properties.

Answer (score 6):

You could try with gradient projection, here is a quick implementation in python:

```py
import numpy as np

def project(p, f, gradf, tol=1e-2):
    u = p
    for i in range(100):
        g = gradf(u)
        v = u - f(u) * g / np.linalg.norm(g)**2
        if np.linalg.norm(u - v) < tol:
            return v
        else:
            u = v
    return v
```

For example, using it to project a point $p = (1, 1, 1)^T$ onto Ellipsoid from your first example:

```py
def f(x):
    return 4 * x[0]**2 + 9 * x[1]**2 + x[2]**2 - 1

def gradf(x):
    return np.array([8 * x[0], 18 * x[1], 2 * x[2]])

p = np.array([1, 1, 1])
q = project(p, f, gradf)
q, np.linalg.norm(p - q)
```

we get a closest point $q$ on the surface and distance $\left\lVert p - q \right\rVert_{2}$:

```
(array([0.31380786, 0.0296923 , 0.77342578]), 1.2098316328577217)
```

Similarly, for Clebsch surface from your second example:

```py
def f(x):
    return (64 * x[0]**3 + 48 * x[0]**2 * x[2] - 192 * x[1]**2 * x[0]
            + 48 * x[1]**2 * x[2] - 31 * x[2]**3 - 54 * x[2]**2 - 24 * x[2])

def gradf(x):
    return np.array([192 * x[0]**2 - 192 * x[1]**2 + 96 * x[0] * x[2],
                     -384 * x[0] * x[1] + 96 * x[1] * x[2],
                     -24 + 48 * x[0]**2 + 48 * x[1]**2 - 108 * x[2] - 93 * x[2]**2])

p = np.array([1, 1, 1])
q = project(p, f, gradf)
q, np.linalg.norm(p - q)
```

gives:

```
(array([1.1304619 , 0.62158043, 0.83049637]), 0.4346874290585481)
```

And here is a figure of surface plots with points and projections:
[image: examples]